# "Could not find 'capistrano'" in cap deploy:setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am very confuse about it.

```
darien:testr fschuindt$ cap deploy:setup
/Users/fschuindt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'capistrano' (>= 0) among 47 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/fschuindt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/fschuindt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/cap:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/fschuindt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Somebody have any idea of what's happening?
It seems a local problem, but I have Capistrano installed here.

Comment: can you send me output of cap -vT and GEMFILE?

Comment: have you "bundle install" before ?

Comment: It's a little embarrassing to say, but I have solved this problem and don't know how. It's works now, but I don't changed anything.